# return type of synchronous method in gwt

Tags: gwt

I created a sample GWT application where the synchronous method returns a List. The code compiles and I'm able to run it successfully. But it prints the message what is there in "onFailure" method on client side implementation of server side code. Can List be given as return type to synchronous method in GWT?

Comment: Pls post the relevant part of the code and the exception you're getting

Comment: you mentioned `onFailure` method, are you sure it's a synchronous method ?

Comment: synchronous or asynchronous ?